# Azure ML Studio Notebook Security Issue when accessing Blobs

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud

Inside Azure ML Studio I am trying to invoke an Azure Model from a notebook but it cannot access the blobs from URL.

```
    ml_client.online_endpoints.invoke(
        endpoint_name='VALIDENDPOINTNAMEREDACTED',
        request_file=temp_file.name,
        deployment_name='openai-whisper-large-15',
        auth=service_principal_auth
    )
```

I am attempting to invoke the whisper model on one of my blobs which contains an mp3.

Inside the request file is this

```
{"input_data": {"audio": ["https://<validstorageresourcename>.blob.core.windows.net/test/test.mp3"], "language": ["en"]}}
```

There is an HTTPS error as the endpoint does not have permissions to read the blob.

When I generate a SAS for the 'test.mp3' blob and put that link in the request file the model runs, so the problem is with processing this type of link.

I am looking to give permission to my AzureMLStudio applications and I used RBAC to make it a contributor but it still cannot read the blobs this way (I also made the endpoint a contributor and nothing). Is there a workaround, or will I  have to generate SAS's or download locally into the notebook and run inference locally then delete?

Answer (score 0):

> There is an HTTPS error, as the endpoint does not have permissions to read the blob.

The above error occurs when your application or user doesn't have proper permission to access the blobs.

> Is there a workaround, or will I have to generate SAS's or download locally into the notebook and run inference locally then delete?

For accessing blob storage from an AzureML application, you need a role to access blob storage. The role is **`Storage Blob Data Contributor`**.

Go to the portal -> storage accounts -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add -> Add role assignments -> storage-blob-data-contributor role to the storage account.

**Portal:**

[image]

Once assigned, I verified it from my portal.

**Portal:**
[image]

Now, you can use the same code to access the blobs from the URL through Azure ML notebooks.

**Reference:**
[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-blob-data-contributor)

Comment: I've tried giving both Storage Account Contributor and Storage Blob Data Contributor to the ML endpoint and workspace with no luck, any reason why?